# Why is the C# WPF Microsoft System.Windows.Media.FormattedText reporting the wrong text width?

Tags: c#, wpf, width, string-length

I have a WPF application that includes a TextBlock. The thing is I don't know the width of the TextBlock I need because I don't know ahead of time how many characters are in the text that's to be displayed in the TextBlock. So I estimate the width based on the font, font size and the character count. Here's what I do:

```
static public int SetContentWidth(int fontSizeResult, string ContentText, string fontComboBox )
        {
            FormattedText formattedText = new FormattedText(ContentText,
                System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-us"),
                FlowDirection.LeftToRight,
                new Typeface(fontComboBox),
                fontSizeResult,
                Brushes.Black);

            formattedText.SetFontSize((fontSizeResult + GetHorizontalSizeMultiplyer(fontSizeResult)) * (96.0 / 72.0), 0, 5);
            double acwidth = formattedText.Width;

            return (Int32)Math.Round(acwidth);
        }
```

The problem is that the formattedText.Width given is always wrong! For example the text "text1 text2 text3 text4 text5" reports a width of 373. If I double that text "text1 text2 text3 text4 text5 text1 text2 text3 text4 text5" the reported width (should be double) is 558 (not 746)!
What's going on here?!
Can anybody please tell me how to calculate the width of a text string in pixels!

Thanks in advance for your help
Steve

Comment: I can't replicate the issue if I set the `FormattedText` with static values. It's something in one of your bound properties or your `SetFontSize` call that changing the values.

Comment: Tronald,
The problem is that if you use SetFontSize to calculate the width of a string "text1 text2 text3 text4 text5" for example, you get 327 (Calibri size 16) but if you DOUBLE that string to "text1 text2 text3 text4 text5text1 text2 text3 text4 text5" you get 635, NOT THE DOUBLE of 327!